# Can I put a value to input of already installed program with powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I need to put a serialkey to already installed VMware Workstation with powershell. I know, that you can install it with parameter SERIALNUMBER="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx", but there must be another way. I tried to start VMware with default instalation an put license key in GUI window, but it doesn't work at all.

[How that GUI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQvmR.png)

Do you have some ideas? Or is it even possible?

&"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware.exe" /s  SERIALNUMBER="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"

I tried run that app with this values, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can experiment with `SendMessage` and WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, or WM_KEY to send an input. That requires that you find the window handle by enumerating the windows and windows classes. But each Windows application may handle these messages differently.

Comment: The program might be sensitive to quoting. When calling commands, PowerShell removes double-quotation marks if it thinks they are not necessary (when there is no whitespace in argument). Try to use `Start-Process` which keeps the commandline as-is: `Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware.exe' -ArgumentList '/s SERIALNUMBER="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"'`

Comment: Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware.exe' -ArgumentList '/s SERIALNUMBER="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"'  -I have tried, it doesn't work too :-(

Comment: From a quick search, it appears the parameter is only available for the installer, not for the already-installed vmware.exe: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMware-Workstation-8-SERIALNUMBER-property-doesn-t-work/td-p/304903